# How can I get the opacity of a surface to decrease as Abs[y] increases?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to create a plot of a hyperboloid surface like the one shown below with the surface becoming more transparent as it moves away from the origin along the $y$-axis, so the surface is more opaque near the $xz$-plane, but it fades out as `Abs[y]` increases.

I played around with `ColorFunction`, but had no success.

```
viewRange = 3;
ContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1, 
  {x, -viewRange, viewRange}, {y, -viewRange, viewRange}, {z, -viewRange, viewRange}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Glow[Red]}, 
  Mesh -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: hyperboloid]

Comment: It's a bit annoying that you neglected to provide values for `a,b,c`.

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
viewRange = 3;
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 - y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -viewRange, viewRange}, {y, -viewRange, 
  viewRange}, {z, -viewRange, viewRange}, Mesh -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 

 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {Glow[Red], Opacity[1 - Abs[y/viewRange]]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm. That's weird. On version 11.3 on macos, I obtain only a grayscale image with this `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher strange, I will better post full code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I can reproduce with Kuba's new code. Switching to just `Red`, instead of `Glow[Red]` fixed the issue.

Comment: Still the same: everything in gray. And something really weird happens with the transparency; it's so weird, I cannot explain...

Comment: @rcollyer I do not agree. In OSX, switching to `Red` does not produce the same effect than `Glow[Red]`. In 11.2, they look different. In 11.3 using `Red` gives the same result than in 11.2, and I confirm that `Glow[whatevercolor]` looks like `Glow[Black]` (=== the grayscale version).

Comment: @rcollyer The two examples in the -Applications-  section of the `Glow` docs are totally black in 11.3 (OSX) but ALSO in the online version http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Glow.html !!?

Comment: @SquareOne you mis-interpreted my first statement. I meant I reproduced Henrik's issue. The online version reflects the same issue because the docs are processed on macs. Either way, I'll file a bug.

Answer (score 4):

We can have the opacity drop off according to a Gaussian:

```
With[{a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, vr = 3},
     ContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1,
                   {x, -vr, vr}, {y, -vr, vr}, {z, -vr, vr},
                   BoundaryStyle -> None, 
                   ColorFunction -> (Directive[Glow[Red], Specularity[White, 3], 
                                               RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051,
                                                        Exp[-#2^2/3]]] &), 
                   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
                   Lighting -> {{"Ambient",
                                 RGBColor[0.30100577, 0.224146685, 0.090484535]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2642166, 0.1833123, 0.0426153],
                                 ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2642166, 0.1833123, 0.0426153],
                                 ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]},
                                {"Directional", RGBColor[0.2642166, 0.1833123, 0.0426153],
                                 ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, Mesh -> False]]
```

[image: one-sheet hyperboloid with varying opacity]

Answer (score 2):

I could make it work by putting the opacity value as forth argument (alpha level) of `RGBColor`. I had to deactivate `Glow`, though.

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
c = 1;
viewRange = 3;
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1, {x, -viewRange, 
  viewRange}, {y, -viewRange, viewRange}, {z, -viewRange, viewRange},
 (*ContourStyle\[Rule]{Glow[Red]},*)
 Mesh -> False,
 BoundaryStyle -> None,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, {
    RGBColor[1, 0, 0, Clip[2 - Abs[y], {0., 1.}]]}
   ]
 ]
```

[image]